# Sub specie precariae linguae or sub specie linguae precariae?

Tags: grammar-choice, genitive

This is a rather small doubt, but I'm currently a bit confused regarding the proper word order of an adjective-noun under a genitive form of the sort "sub specie..." Am I correct in assuming the adjective should also be in the genitive case along the noun and is the first word order proper?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the adjective must also be in the genitive. Latin adjectives always agree with the nouns they modify in case, number and gender.

The word order is up to you. For the adjective's position relative to its noun, Latin has no fast rule. Both variants of yours are perfectly fine.